# Learning Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Ali from Senegal. I am 60 years old(maybe this is my real problem - smiley!!!).

I am learning Flutter and Dart. Today I wanted to use a list of given data model (it's name is Mortalite, please see in the code below).
I try to use dartpad. I am very sad because I do not understand why the following snipet does not run:

//https://www.dartpad.dev/

```
void main(){
  print('Beginning');
  
  List<Mortalite>pertes;
  
  var causes = ['Bla0', 'Bla1', 'Bla2', 'Bla3'];
  var lstDate = ['21/09/2020', '22/09/2020', '23/09/2020', '24/09/2020'];
  var perteInst = [2, 4, 3, 1];
  var total=0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    total += perteInst[i];
    print(i);                           // prints only '0'
    
    pertes[i] = new Mortalite(
      causesPerte: causes[i],
      datePerte: lstDate[i], 
      perteInstant:perteInst[i],
      totalPertes: total);
      };
   print(pertes.length);                // nothing printed
   print('Why?');                       // nothing printed
 }

class Mortalite {
  String datePerte;
  String causesPerte;
  int perteInstant; // pertes du jour
  int totalPertes; // Total des pertes.
  Mortalite(
    {this.datePerte, 
     this.causesPerte, 
     this.perteInstant, 
     this.totalPertes}
  );
}
```

Thank you well for help.
A.KOTE

Comment: an addition to @Zero answer, you just initialized pertes, without assigning a value to pertes. So when you called pertes[i], it is the same as null[i], which will throw error. So by assign pertes with an empty list (aka [] ), your problem is solved.

Comment: Not true actually. We cannot assign value to the list element if it doesn't exist. Even if you have an empty list initialized, you cannot assign elements to individual index if they don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

The reason above code doesn't work is because you have List pertes initialized and you are passing to the elements of pertes. When you try to pass to 0 index of pertes, it cannot find it and it throws range error because pertes doesn't have an index 0 yet. Please take a look at fix below and let me know if you need help with anything.

```
void main(){
  print('Beginning');
  
  List<Mortalite>pertes=[];
  
  var causes = ['Bla0', 'Bla1', 'Bla2', 'Bla3'];
  var lstDate = ['21/09/2020', '22/09/2020', '23/09/2020', '24/09/2020'];
  var perteInst = [2, 4, 3, 1];
  var total=0;

  for (int i = 0; i < causes.length; i++) {
    total += perteInst[i];                           // prints only '0'
    
    pertes.add (new Mortalite(
      causesPerte: causes[i],
      datePerte: lstDate[i], 
      perteInstant:perteInst[i],
      totalPertes: total));
                };
   print(pertes.length);                // nothing printed                      // nothing printed
 }

class Mortalite {
  String datePerte;
  String causesPerte;
  int perteInstant; // pertes du jour
  int totalPertes; // Total des pertes.
  Mortalite(
    {this.datePerte, 
     this.causesPerte, 
     this.perteInstant, 
     this.totalPertes}
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi,You are MAGIC!!! The '=[]' solved the problem. Thank you a lot. A.KOTE

Comment: No problem. Have a good time Mr. Kote. Flutter community is with you :)